# Using http_accept_language gem on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, http-accept-language

I'm trying to use this gem to determine the user's preferred language, and running into some trouble.

```
undefined local variable or method http_accept_language for #<HomeController:0x964f5ec>
```

I included the gem in the Gemfile, ran bundle install, and restarted the server multiple times. Why doesn't my app recognize the gem?

Also, in my ApplicationController I wrote the following method:

```
def set_i18n_locale
 http_accept_language.user_preferred_languages
 available = %w{en kr}
 params[:locale] = http_accept_language.preferred_language_from(available)
    if params[:locale]
        I18n.locale = params[:locale]
    end
end
```

One thing I don't understand is the second line,
`http_accept_language.user_preferred_languages`

From https://github.com/iain/http_accept_language, this is supposed to return a sorted array. I thought I had to store the array into some variable and use it, but the author just throws the method like that. How does that work? Can't I just do the following?

```
available = %w{en kr}
params[:locale] = http_accept_language.language_region_compatible_from(available)
```

I am just a little confused by the author's explanation.

Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE:**
the gem, http_accept_language, doesn't seem to be installed successfully. It's on the gem list, but when I try to uninstall it, the error message shows that it's not installed. Why does this happen?

```
max@max-VirtualBox:~/appe$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
...
http_accept_language (1.0.2)
...

max@max-VirtualBox:~/app$ sudo gem uninstall http_accept_language
INFO:  gem "http_accept_language" is not installed
```

Comment: I can't figure out which platform you are using, but I think you didn't have problem installing it, I think your "sudo gem" accessed a different ruby.

Comment: One more thing, you are asking two things, you could make the question much more readable if you just removed everything from "Also, " to "UPDATE:". I pretty sure you can figure out whatever you meant to ask there after the main question is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have to use the gem to implement the feature I wanted.

```
  def set_i18n_locale
    unless params[:locale]
        params[:locale] = extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
    end
    available = ['en', 'kr']
    if available.include? params[:locale]
        I18n.locale = params[:locale]
    end
  end

  def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
    request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
  end

  def default_url_options
    { :locale => I18n.locale }
  end
```

[Official Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) and [Agile Development](http://pragprog.com/book/rails2/agile-web-development-with-rails) helped a lot.

Comment: It is a bad thing this code has made such influential material, it is poor man's content negotiation.

Comment: Your code is accurate only when user's browsers first preferred language is 'en' or 'kr'. If the user preferred languages does not match-up with your available then you need to specify a default locale to fall-back for.

Specific answer to your original question,
As @michelpm has mentioned already. You need to specify `gem 'http_accept_language', '~ 2.0.0.pre'` in your Gemfile.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `request.user_preferred_languages` instead of `http_accept_language.user_preferred_languages`.

Answer (score 2):

In [the documentation states](https://github.com/iain/http_accept_language) that since version 2.0, the gem is a Rack middleware, but the problem is that [the only 2.0 version released in June 2012](https://rubygems.org/gems/http_accept_language) is [only a pre-release](http://semver.org/). Therefore, to get the version 2.0 you need to do this:

```
gem 'http_accept_language', '~> 2.0.0.pre'
```

Comment: This solution helped me but when Rails reloads app after change was made the problem appears again. Rails 3.2.13, ruby 2.0.0-p195, Development env. By the way I've found suited me solution here: https://github.com/iain/http_accept_language/pull/19

Answer (score 0):

As for me solution was to apply @DouweM PR from the github. Here is the line from the  Gemfile:

```
gem 'http_accept_language', :git => 'https://github.com/DouweM/http_accept_language', :branch => 'no-middleware-no-crash'
```

Answer (score 0):

put in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'http_accept_language', '~> 2.0.0.pre'
```

and then in the code use env aka:

```
env.http_accept_language
```

works for me.

```
% bundle show|grep acc
    * http_accept_language (2.0.0.pre)
```